twiML to redirect a call to a new studio flow
I have a studio flow (A) which includes a twiML redirect widget.
This executes the following twiMl. The URL is webhook address of a different studio Flow (B)
<Response>
    <Say>Your message here</Say> <Redirect>https://webhooks.twilio.com/v1/Accounts/*********/Flows/FWe7b1bc2af0cead61944713892765c223?FlowEvent=return</Redirect>
</Response>

I hear the "Your message here" and then I get an error message.
In the logs I see a 400 Bad request against the webhook address. This means the redirect is happening, but its failing.
Is it possible to cause a redirect to another studio flow using twiML?
